# Creating a RichTextEditor with INPUT Events level 2

Tags: javascript, input

```
Document.execCommand
```

Is now depreciated ,
I read an article that it's replacement is INPUT EVENTS LEVEL 2
But there were no Examples

I don't know about events level 2
So my question is how to implement input events level 2 to achieve WYSIWYG EDITOR

I tried document.execCommand but it's now deprecated I also searched a good article about input events level 2 but I founded nothing

Comment: I mean I heard of input events level 2

Comment: But I don't know what's it

Comment: So should I use selections and ranges or should I use level 2 but I really want to use input level 2 just an example

Comment: Is level 2 just clipboard api ? Or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Level 2 is in [W3C's draft stage](https://w3c.github.io/input-events/) and may take years to come to fruition. Currently `execCommand` is the best way to create a rich text editor without losing your mind.

When it comes to rich editors, `execCommand` is one of those exceptions where you'll be advised to use a deprecated API. Its been deprecated for years but browsers can't live without it so its not going anywhere.